# Which .nuget package includes String.Compare with StringComparison argument?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, .net-standard

I have tried to look for documentation for which pagacke i have to include in my .Net standard Class library.

I'm porting files from my Asp.Net Core 2.1 Web project into my .Net standard 2.0 class library and its now missing the StringComparison argument from the String.Contains.

```
public bool Contains(String value, StringComparison comparisonType)
```

[image]

Is there a way to include this in a nuget package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is included to the [System.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/) and you can't use it in **netstandard2.0**. You need target to **netcoreapp2.1** or install this package, but it is a bad idea because it has dependencies to Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms  and Microsoft.NETCore.Targets

[You can see this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20846)

Comment: Glad to have been of help